# How "kinematic" rigid bodies are implemented in physics engines

Tags: computational-physics, constraints, lagrange-multiplier

In most physics engines there's this concept of "static" bodies, which act as rigid bodies with infinite mass. Then there are "kinematic" bodies that act as static bodies, but their motion is simulated by animation data or by user specifying position or velocity directly. And finally there are the "dynamic" bodies which are physics-driven rigid bodies with non-infinite mass.

I'm curious how these kinematic bodies fit into Lagrangian mechanics, and how the equality and inequality constraints are resolved for these. Say we want to simulate a hinge joint between rigid bodies. For two dynamic rigid bodies we can define a position constraint and apply constraint forces to satisfy the constraint. But how would we go about simulating this joint for a kinematic and a dynamic rigid body?

I can't find any information on this subject, and any insight on these types of kinematic bodies would be helpful.